# Syntax with Passing a function into another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm writing a function that returns a data frame and I'd like to have one of the columns of this data frame to essentially take a column of data, pass it into a predifined function and then set that as a column of the new data frame.

So i set the function up to take a set of data, a function which applies logic and the set of data which that function uses.

I was able to get it to work if I use .apply in the final line of of my code that is arrowed.

```
bt_data['Position'] = signal_data.apply(trade_logic)
```

but I was advised to use np.select instead of apply b/c it's vectorized and I was wondering since my function is using vectorization is there a better syntax to use to set a column called bt_data['Positions'] to just be the trade_logic function applied on mlr_data['Slope'}

```
Slope
3.98
3.78
-6.67
-17.6
-18.05
-14.48
-12.25
-13.9
-16.89
-13.3
-13.19
-18.63
-26.36
-26.23
-22.94
-23.23
-15.7
-11.01
-12.65
0.33
14.85
14.79
6.8
2.57
```

Code:

```
def trade_logic(x):
    conditions = [x.between(0, 10, inclusive=False), x.between(-10, 0, inclusive=False)]
    values = ['Long', 'Short']
    np.select(conditions, values, 'Flat')

def slope_test(x):
    if x >0 and x<20:
        return 'Long'
    elif x<0 and x>-20:
        return 'Short'
    else:
        return 'Flat'

def backtest_data(data,trade_logic,signal_data):

    bt_data = pd.DataFrame()

    bt_data['TickChange'] = bt_data['C']-bt_data['C'].shift(1)
    bt_data['CumTickChange'] = bt_data['TickChange'].cumsum()
    bt_data['Position'] = trade_logic(signal_data)  < ------

    return bt_data

results = backtest_data(mlr_data,trade_logic,mlr_data['Slope'])
print(results)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Where are you passing a function to another function? The line you're pointing at is passing the `signal_data` parameter to `trade_logic`. Which seems to be just a Series passed in by the caller.

Comment: im trying to get the syntax to use the the trade_logic() function in the backtest_data function.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is not that you don't know how to pass `trade_logic`, or how to call it; rather, it's that your `trade_logic` function can only take a single value, and you want to know how to rewrite it to take a whole Series/array (and ideally do vectorized work on it), righr?

Comment: If so, please edit your question to make that clearer, and also give us a [mcve] so we can figure out the intended shape of your DataFrame instead of having to guess at it.

Comment: yea i'm trying to figure out a syntax to apply my function trade_logic in my backtest_data function without using the apply function that i have to use since i'm assuming that renders the vectorization of the function useless